# Error while loading csv data via user stage (internal sage) into a snowflake table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-stage

I get the below error when I'm trying to load the data from the user stage into a snowflake table.

> File '@~/vehicles.csv.gz', line 9, character 31
> Row 9, column "VEHICLE"["CATEGORY":4]
> If you would like to continue loading when an error is encountered, use other values such as        'SKIP_FILE' or 'CONTINUE'
> for the ON_ERROR option. For more information on loading options,
> please  run 'info loading_data' in a SQL client.

Even though I have added `field_optionally_enclosed_by = '"'` in the file format which is as below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT CSV_NO_HEADER_BLANK_LINES
    type = 'CSV'
    field_delimiter = ','
    field_optionally_enclosed_by = '"'
    skip_header = 0
    skip_blank_lines = true;
```

Here is the COPY INTO command that I'm using:

```
COPY INTO VEHICLE
     FROM @~/vehicles.csv.gz
     file_format = CSV_NO_HEADER_BLANK_LINES;
```

Below is the 9th line having an issue as per the error.

```
"Dodge", "ATS", "2017", "Sedan,Wagon"
```

Below are the before and after rows of data for 9th row:

```
"GMC", "Titan Crew Cab", "2011", "Coupe"
"Dodge", "MX-5 Miata", "2014", "Hatchback"
"Dodge", "ATS", "2017", "Sedan,Wagon"
"Volvo", "Savana 2500 Cargo", "2019", "suv"
"Mercedes-Benz", "Armada", "2014", "Coupe Sedan"
```

Help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi - please can you update your question with the COPY INTO command you are running and also add  two rows of data from before and after this row

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have spaces between each field, not just the delimiter. If you add this line to your file format it should resolve the issue:

```
TRIM_SPACE = TRUE
```